# Finding the sum of subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on a very large array of subarrays full of numbers that I want to reduce into one sum for each subarray.

Example:

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
});
console.log(arr);

//I want arr to equal [[6], [15]];
```

My solution just returns the original array element

Comment: `arr.map(a => a.reduce((p,c) => p+c))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
var newArr = [];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  item = item.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
  newArr.push([item]);
});
console.log(newArr);
```

To be a bit more concise, you can use the values passed to the forEach callback: the item you're currently iterating through, the index of that item, and the array itself:

```
arr.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
  array[index] = [array[index].reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
  })];
});
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`.reduce` doesn't modify the original array. You can use `.map` and return the new value, like this:

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

var newArr = arr.map(function(item) {
  return [item.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  })];
});
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with map and arrow functions:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
var result = arr.map(item => item.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
console.log(result); // [ 6, 15 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

**ES5 Syntax**

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

arr.map(function (item) {
  return item.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return  a+b;
  });
})
```

[image]

**ES6 Syntax**

```
arr.map(item => {
  return item.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want?

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];

arr = arr.map(function(item,i) {
  return [item.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  })];
});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the summed result to be in their own list, I would break the problem down in to 2 steps:

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]];
const sumList = (xs) => [xs.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0)];

alert(arr.map(sumList)); //=> [[6], [15]]
```